# Deleting and updating a smart contract

Tags: azure-blockchain-workbench

In practice how should you go about updating your smart contract logic. Smart contracts are immutable by design. You can't delete it since Azure Blockchain Workbench API doesn't support deleting a contract at this moment (from the API documentation: Applications - Application Delete, Currently not implemented.) And if you try to deploy an updated version of the .sol and .json file through the Azure Blockchain Workbench web app the changes are ignored when creating a new instance of the contract. This leads you ho have versioned contracts over time: Contract1, Contract2, ..., ContractN. So how should you deal with this correctly?

Comment: RE: "the changes are ignored when creating a new instance of the contract". Are you saying that each new version of the contract is identical to the previous; that the changes aren't getting deployed?

Comment: Yes, that is how it looks like to me.